# scala commit and rollback transactionally

Tags: scala, playframework

I need to rollback queries if one of them is failed

I've tried this but it doesnt take parameter

```
    val trans = (
    for {
      insertPerson <- PersonDal.insert
      deletePerson <- PersonDal.delete
    } yield ()).transactionally

  def futureTest = db.run(trans)
```

and this is my services that need `case class` parameter

```
    def updateEntryInsuranceRate(insurancerate: EntryInsuranceRate): Future[Int] = {
    db.run(DalEntryInsuranceRate.updateEntryInsuranceRate(insurancerate))
  }

  def deleteEntryInsuranceRate(insurancerate: EntryInsuranceRate): Future[Int] = {
    db.run(DalEntryInsuranceRate.deleteEntryInsuranceRate(insurancerate))
  }
```

how can I use `transactionally` or other `method` on my queries for commit and rollback?